# how to find the most common elements in a list (using all())

Tags: python

I'm trying to return the most common elements in a list (statistical mode). Unfortunately I don't know how to use the `all` with an iterable. This is what it looks like if I don't use all():

```
def large(a):
for i in set(a):
    for j in set(a):
        if a.count(i)<a.count(j):
            break
return i
```

However I know that this can be written more eloquently. Can someone please write the more eloquent version as well?
I believe it is something along the lines of:

```
[i for i,j in set(a) if all(a.count(i)>a.count(j)]
```

This code has 2 issues. First is that `set(a)` needs a second value to unpack and the second is the `all` doesn't work here.

Help me out please. Thanks!

Example: in `{'a','a','b','b','b','c'}` you would expect '`b`' to be the largest element

Comment: `all()` isn't an iterator, [it's a built-in.](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all)

Comment: Oops your right I meant to say how to use all with an iterable

Comment: I've linked you to the documentation page; that should give you a headstart.

Comment: You first function does not match your description: It returns the first item which does not occur *least* frequently, where order of items is non-deterministic (depends on `set` implementation and item hashes). So for `[1,1,2,3,3,3]` your code may return `1`. Another issue: Efficiency. Calling count repeatedly is O(n^2), you can do it in O(n) if you build a `collections.counter` and then look for `max(a, key=counts.get)`.

Comment: Are you looking for a ***list*** to be returned, or a ***number*** that represent "the largest number of elements in a list" (as you state). Your words say one, but your code imply the other ..  Can you please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK - understand your question now. The code below is not how one should generally solve this problem. But it's OK for learning how all() works. Please note that it's far less efficient than Counter. Interestingly it will return every element that is most frequent - so might be useful when accurate handling of multi-modal data is required.

```
>>> q = list("aaabbbbcc")
>>> q
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
>>> r = set(q)
>>> r
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> [x for x in r if all([q.count(x) >= q.count(y) for y in r])]
['b']
```

Comment: In your first example, `all()` shows up as true when everything is lower case. Is it not possible to have `all()` show up as true under an if statement? That's essentially what I was hoping to do...perhaps I am misunderstanding the ALL function

Comment: It is - I've posted example which should clear it up for you :)

Comment: Thanks!!! The reason I wanted this answer vs the counter answer is because I've seen the `All()` used in this fashion, it reduced the lines of code considerably and I wanted to start coding like that instead of my multiple nested `for` loops. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common(a):
    return Counter(a).most_common(1)[0][0]
```

If you absolutely have to do this with `all` - which I don't think is the best approach - try

```
def most_common(a):
    a_count = [(i, a.count(i)) for i in set(a)]
    for i,c in a_count:
        if all(c >= cc for ii,cc in a_count):
           return i
```

Comment: Thanks but I was aware of the counter, I'm looking to learn the all() function so that I can use it in the future

Comment: what does the simultaneous ii and cc refer to? (why do you need two i's and two c's?

Comment: @Chowza: I use that as short-hand for "the other i" and "the other c" (since I can't use i' and c' ;-)